# Android:Create test with fill in the blank type ques

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a test in which i have fill in the blank type question.Currently i am rendering it like -

TextView

EditText

TextView

But i want to render it like -

TextView EditText TextView

how can i do it, so that it work in the case where text in first textview is of multiple line
can anyone please help.

Comment: Use relative layout. It is not that hard and I don't think even worth asking question.

Comment: i have a single linear layout with vertical orientation in xml and i am dynamically adding textview and edittext in it.

Comment: @VishwasSharma how will you render it if it is like -
hi hello it is text please.............................write something in the given_________blank

Comment: If you are dynamically adding it, just change the orientation to  `horizontal` and I think your work will be done. Cheers...

Comment: @Agr1909 i think you use relative layout...i know its little difficult in starting but when u start doing it you going to love it..[try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577570/android-relativelayout-how-to-put-two-elements-on-the-same-line).

Comment: @Agr1909 post your xml

Answer (score 0):

Use horizontal layout to display all the elements in the same row organized by columns.

Something like

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/second_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
  </LinearLayout>
```

I hope it helps you :)