# Make only parts of text editable in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

For my Android application, I would like there to be a sentence on the screen (a `TextView` or an `EditText` or something in that direction) which looks like this:

> The red ___________ jumped over the lazy dog.

where the user can click on the underscore and complete the sentence themselves. I could accomplish this by having the entire sentence represented by an `EditText`, but I would like the Strings `The red`  and `jumped over the lazy dog.` to be uneditable.

I have a lot of sentences like that which should be completed, so hardcoding the uneditable parts of the string as an image or something will not work. How do I do this?

Comment: You could place the editview in between the textviews.

Comment: @Popeye How do I make sure that the TextViews and EditView are lined up correctly for sentences of various lengths and lines?

Comment: You can use dynamically draw like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788386/set-unchangeable-some-part-of-edittext-android

Comment: @Popeye Unfortunately that is not a useful solution since the sentences are of various lengths and can take multiple lines, so a solution like that is not going to be flexible enough. I am amazed how hard this simple task is for Android.

Comment: I still believe that relative layout would work, by keeping editviews in textviews whatever the number of lines in a paragraph.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/11577570/4002680

Comment: @Sid did you find a solution?

Comment: I ended up using the addTextChangedListener. It did not achieve exactly what I wanted, but close enough.

Comment: @Sid did you get any robust solution for this?

Comment: @ShashankSrivastava No, just a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [addTextChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)). Using [afterTextChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) you may control uneditable parts of text by change it back after editing.

Comment: This is perhaps a functioning solution but it's really bad design. I don't want the user to be able to change the uneditable parts of the sentence at all, no matter that the sentence is changed back later.